# Data type mismatch help MS Access VBA

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I keep getting a Data type mismatch when trying to run a lookup. I have a table tWorkOrder and has a Short Text column salesOrderNo Number column workOrderNo and  Short Text lineKey I am searching for the lineKey value in my lookup.

```
    Dim lineKeyOW, SoNo, WTSo As String
    SoNo = 0135487
    WTSo = 2
    lineKeyOW = Nz(DLookup("lineKey", "tWorkOrder", "salesOrderNo = '" & soNo & "' AND workOrderNo = '" & WTSo & "'"), "NA")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this will be better

```
Dim lineKeyOW As String
Dim SoNo as String
Dim WTSo As Long

SoNo = 0135487
WTSo = 2
lineKeyOW = Nz(DLookup("lineKey", "tWorkOrder", "salesOrderNo = '" & soNo & "' AND workOrderNo = " & WTSo ), "NA")
```

First, `workOrderNo` column being **Number** datatype, you should not surround it's value with `'`

Then,  never do this :

```
Dim lineKeyOW, SoNo, WTSo As String
```

Because it is equivalent to this

```
Dim lineKeyOW As Variant, SoNo As Variant, WTSo  As String
```

Which is plain wrong for several reasons.

If you really want an *inline* `dim` declaration, you should do

```
Dim lineKeyOW As String, SoNo As String, WTSo  As String
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling it had something to do with the " and ' I always have had a hard time with them.

Comment: @Kevin That will come with practicing.

Comment: Also thank you for the explanation on declaring variables that was very helpful.